# Database Table row value replacing mentioned name

Tags: mysql, sql

user will give sms content by following format

```
Dear #name#,This is testing SMS.
```

I want to replace #name# place holder by table existing value.there are 100k rows.

Data:

[image]

Output:

[image: Sample Output result:]

Comment: Why isn't there `Dear llalal...` etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works! Concate your column value between the text, if your text is static

```
SELECT 'Dear'+columname+', This is testing SMS' 
FROM tablename;
```

Comment: You have to add some where conds also to bypass unwanted users.

Comment: @Bibin I have to update table existing value by user provided #name# placeholder . sms text will be static but placeholder value will be table rows value.that means placeholder value will be dynamic. is it possible ??

Comment: @hmamun yes possbile, please give the table structure of both tables

Comment: I have only one table. table value will be updated by user provided #name# place holder. \n
example: 
existing value in column sms_text: xyz 
user provided content "Dear #name# , this is testing sms.." 
now sms_text column value will be "Dear xyz , this is testing sms.." 
hope you understand it.